# SharedViewModel not clearing when poping fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using a shared view model like [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing)

But the problem is that when I clear my last fragment, I want to clear the viewmodel, or kill its instance, but somehow it survives when I leave the last fragment that uses it

How can I programatically clear this viewmodel ?

I use it like this

### Fragment A

```
private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated() {

     model.getTotal().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { cartTotal ->
                total = cartTotal
            })

    }
```

From fragment B I sent the total

### Fragment B

```
private val model: SharedViewModel by activityViewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated() {

     model.setTotal = 10
}
```

But when leaving Fragment A with that data (doing popBackStack since I'm using navigation components) it does not clear the viewmodel, instead when I open again my fragment , the data stills there

I suspect that the viewmodel is tied with my Container Activity and not the lifecycle of the fragments itself, so

How can I remove the instance or clear my viewmdel when I hit my last fragment ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the [returning a result APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-programmatic#returning_a_result) in Navigation `2.3.0` (currently in alpha)? It does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @ianhanniballake , will take a look

Comment: @ianhanniballake one more question, at my use case will I need to do a remove() before using getLiveData() in my Fragment A ? since if I dont put it I will be getting the same livedata after I pop fragment a and enter again, im right ?

Comment: The LiveData won't have any result the first time you're in Fragment A, so you'd only need to remove if you're going back and forth between A and B multiple times (and even then, I assume the new result would override the previous?)

Comment: yes but if from Fragment B, I send back data to Fragment A, after I pop Fragment A and enters again in it, will the livedata persist ? Or it will be removed after I pop Fragment A ?

Comment: After you pop Fragment A, the ViewModel associated with the back stack entry for Fragment A will be destroyed

Comment: Thanks a lot Ian, can you post this as an answer so I can check it ? , also, there is a funny thing in your link that val navController ends with a ;

Comment: Another thing is that  `navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData("key")` should be  `navController.currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<String>("key")` in the example, since it cant infer the type string from the value passed to getLiveData

Comment: Do you mind [filing a documentation bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192697) and including a link here? I can pass it along.

Comment: Ian, I have tested the docs with a simple toast that should be displayed from fragment b to fragment A but the livedata is not beign triggered somehow, is ok if I make another question in a bit ?

Comment: My use case has a viewpager that inflates fragments in different tabs, and I need to send information from that viewpager fragment to the container fragment, here the viewpager is Fragment B, and its contained inside Fragment A, this just works for navigating from different destinations and not from included fragments like this ? 
Thanks @ianhanniballake

Comment: If you're using the `childFragmentManager` and a child fragment, you should be using the parent Fragment (i.e., your Fragment A) as the ViewModelStoreOwner, not the activity. Is there a particular reason you're using the activity?

Comment: No, I just need to send data from my inner viewpager fragment, to the fragment that contains that viewpager, I dont get you when you say ViewModelStoreOwner, is that instantiating my viewmodel without activityViewModels() and do it with ViewModelStoreOwner ? thanks for this tips Ian, I'm getting the flow of it

Comment: if its not a bother, can you edit the instantiation of my viewmodel in my Fragment A to be the owner of that viewmodel so when it is destroyed the viewmodel dettachs ? (as the answer of this question) because that is what I need, to store the instance of my viewmodel inside Fragment A, then update that data from fragment b (childframgment) so when Fragment A dies, the viewmodel dies with it @ianhanniballake

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get a ViewModel associated with a parent fragment, your inner fragment should follow the [`by viewModels` JavaDoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#viewmodels) and use:

```
val viewmodel: MYViewModel by viewmodels ({requireParentFragment()})
```

This says to use the parent Fragment as the owner of your ViewModel.

(The parent fragment would use `by viewModels()` as it is accessing its own ViewModels)

Comment: Last question @ianhanniballake , since my viewpager adapter needs a FragmentActivity, my contained viewpager fragment, references to my activity, but is inside Fragment A, so I need to pass data from this contained fragment, to the parent fragment that is Fragment A, but when I try to instantiate the viewmodel it says that it is attached to my activity, and from the adapter I cant setup the parent fragment to be the owner of that viewpager fragment, is there anything I can do there ?

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more clear on the structure of what you're doing and edit your question with more code.

Comment: the issue is that with FragmentStateAdapter I cant pass FragmentManager, so , when I inflate my viewpager inside Fragment A, it takes FragmentActivity which points to my main activity, instead I want to instantiate my adapter with a fragment manager, so I can point to the Fragment A as the container of the viewpager fragments @ianhanniballake  , is that posible im using ViewPager2 ?

Comment: You pass a `Fragment` to use its `childFragmentManager` when using ViewPager2's adapter.

Comment: sorry , I'm a little lost, I will make another question

Comment: There's two `FragmentStateAdapter` constructors - one that takes a `FragmentActivity` that uses the activity's `FragmentManager`. The other is one that takes a `Fragment` and uses its `childFragmentManager`.

Comment: here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698699/sharedviewmodel-from-viewpager2-and-my-parent-fragment

Comment: Thanks Ian, implementing the other one solved my problem you rock !

Answer (score 0):

you can also clear viewModelStore manually after Fragment A destroyed.
something like this :

```
override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    requireActivity().viewModelStore.clear()
}
```

then your viewModel instance will be cleared. for checking this work you can debug `onCleared` method of your viewModel.