# SharedViewModel from viewpager2 and my parent Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-architecture-navigation

So, I have one fragment, lets call it Fragment A, in which I need it to be the main host of my sharedviewmodel.

So I have it like this

```
class FragmentA:Fragment() {

 private val model: SharedViewModel by viewModels()

}
```

Now, inside Fragment A, I set viewpager2 Adapter

```
private fun setupViewPagerWithTabLayout(
        productList: MutableList<Producto>,
        drinkList: MutableList<Producto>
    ) {
        val fragmentList = listOf(
            FragmentProducts.newInstance(productList),
            FragmentProducts.newInstance(drinkList))

        viewPager2.adapter = MyViewPageAdapter(requireActivity(),fragmentList)
        val tabLayoutMediator = TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager2,
            TabLayoutMediator.TabConfigurationStrategy { tab, position ->

                when (position) {
                    0 -> {
                        tab.text = "Option1"
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        tab.text = "Option2"
                    }
                }

            })
        tabLayoutMediator.attach()
    }
```

Here I instantiate my FragmentProduct which is inside Fragment A in a viewpager, but my adapter needs a FragmentActivity

```
class MyViewPageAdapter(fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity,private val fragmentList: List<FragmentProducts>) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return fragmentList.size
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentList[position]
    }
}
```

So, from FragmentProducts that is contained inside FragmentA, I need to share data with this viewmodel, but when I do this to share data from this fragment to FragmentA

```
class FragmentProducts:Fragment(){

    private val model: SharedViewModel by viewModels ({requireParentFragment()})

}
```

I get the followin error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FragmentProducts{6953da8}
>   (3a2f5cbb-113d-4ed2-8f85-56e04fcea356) f0} is not a child Fragment, it
>   is directly attached to com.example.MainActivity@dcc2679

so , this is telling me that FragmentProducts references to my MainActivity, and thats logic because the instance of the adapter takes requireActivity() for FragmentActivity at

```
viewPager2.adapter = MyViewPageAdapter(requireActivity(),fragmentList)
```

So, I need to pass instead of requireActivity() my FragmentA as the host of this viewpager fragment but at my ViewPagerAdapter, I cant pass FragmentStatePagerAdapter or something else to pass my FragmentA as the context for that viewpager

Since Im using viewpager2, is there a way to let FragmentA host FragmentProducts viewpager so I can get it in my FragmentProducts like this

```
private val model: SharedViewModel by viewModels ({requireParentFragment()})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're using `FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity)`. Don't do that. Pass your parent Fragment to `MyViewPageAdapter` and pass **that** to `FragmentStateAdapter`.

```
class MyViewPageAdapter(
    parentFragment: Fragment,
    private val fragmentList: List<FragmentProducts>
) : FragmentStateAdapter(parentFragment) {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, solved the problem ! I'm getting use to the contexts of execution sorry for all the time taken