# Fragment no longer exists with viewPager 2 and TabLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-architecture-components, android-viewpager2

So I have:

Fragment A: here there is a viewPager2 and TabLayout with 2 tabs, Fragment B and C.

Then inside Fragment B , I have a button that goes to a Fragment D outside of the `TabLayout`, there I want get some data, go back and populate a `TextView` on Fragment B in the `TabLayout` in Fragment A.

It works fine until I am on Fragment D and try to get back to Fragment B and get `Fragment no longer exists for key f#0`

How can I fix this?

Fragment A `TabLayout` Adapter:

```
private inner class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fa: FragmentActivity) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa) {
    override fun getItemCount(): Int = 2

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        return if (position == 0) FragmentB()
        else FragmentC()
    }
}
```

Fragment B:

```
findNavController().currentBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.getLiveData<String>("key")?.observe(
        viewLifecycleOwner) { result ->
        binding.textView.text = result
    }
```

Fragment D:

```
fun onGoBack(data: String){
    findNavController().apply {
                    previousBackStackEntry?.savedStateHandle?.set("key", data)
                    navigateUp()
                }
}
```

MainActivity `onSupportNavigateUp`:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

NavGraph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
    android:name="com.example.FragmentA"
    android:label="Fragment A" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
    android:name="com.example.FragmentB"
    android:label="FragmentB" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentC"
    android:name="com.example.FragmentC"
    android:label="FragmentC" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragmentD"
    android:name="com.example.FragmentD"
    android:label="FragmentD" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: thanks to share the nav graph.

Comment: sure, i just added it, it's nothing fancy, i use `findNavController().navigate(fragmentID)`

Comment: Are Fragments B, C pages in the `ViewPager` ?

Comment: yeah, if i set the viewPager with `viewPager.isSaveEnabled = false` it works but i read that doing that it's not a good idea because it can create memory leaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't add `ViewPager` page fragments into the `NavGraph` not only it can introduce memory leaks but also it can introduce `IllegalStateException` for the `navGraph`.. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52540303/android-jetpack-navigation-with-viewpager-and-tablayout#answer-55221335) for more details.

**But what you can do instead to solve this:**

Remove the pager B & C fragments from the navigation graph. So the `navGraph` now contains A & D

Since Fragment B is not a part of the `navGraph`, Make the navigation that you need from the Fragment B to D through Fragment A:

In Fragment B:

```
val fragmentA: FragmentA = requireParentFragment() as FragmentA
fragmentA.openFragmentD()
```

In Fragment A:

```
fun openFragmentD() {
    val  navHostFragment: NavHostFragment = ...;
    val navController: NavController = navHostFragment.getNavController()
    navController.navigate(FragmentADirections.actionFragmentAToFragmentD())
}
```

Likewise: As you need to return some data from D back to B

Then receive this data through Fragment A `onCreateView()`

```
val data = FragmentAArgs.fromBundle(getArguments())
```

Now it's easy to either update the `ViewPager` fragment B with the new data, or you can share it in a shared `ViewModel` between the fragments.

Comment: ohh i see, i tried it and im getting ` java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentBt{34be265} (dfbaabc4-2da5-4fd3-ab88-c2e717c87bb8) f0} is not a child Fragment, it is directly attached to dagger.hilt.android.internal.managers.ViewComponentManager$FragmentContextWrapper@5685b3a` on this line `val fragmentA: FragmentA = requireParentFragment() as FragmentA`

Comment: @Joaco can you check the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60698699/sharedviewmodel-from-viewpager2-and-my-parent-fragment

Comment: It worked,i have a follow up question, i have a editText in `FragmentB`, when  i trigger `openFragmentD()` ,do something and go back to `FragmentB` using `navigateUp()`, it returns the info  from `FragmentD` but  i lose the state of `FramentB` losing the editText text that was there previously, is there a way to preserve the state of `FragmentB` so when i return i dont lose data? Thanks

Comment: @Joaco please check answer of `Elblasy` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59629541/how-to-save-fragment-state-while-navigating-with-navigation-component) it should work to save `EditText` or view state data .. for any complex data use a `ViewModel` to save it. hope that fits your query